# Django: RunSQL: use PostgreSQL COPY command

Tags: django, postgresql, database-migration, psycopg2

I try to run a migration with the following `RunSQL` command:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    operations = [
        RunSQL(
r'''
COPY auth_group (id, name) FROM stdin;
1   TEST-GROUP
\.
''')]
```

It fails like this:

```
File "/home/foo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 63, in execute
     return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "1"
LINE 3: 1 TEST-GROUP
```

Is there `COPY` not allowed in `RunSQL`?

We use psycopg2

Comment: Surely this isn't STDIN, is it? Why don't you use an INSERT statement?

Comment: @DanielRoseman it works with `psql -f myfile.sql`. Both usages look quite similar to a newcomer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `psycopg2` driver exposes `copy_to` and `copy_from` methods that can be used to implement the same behavior as the `psql` client; the key is to use the `RunPython` operation instead of the `RunSQL` operation.

You'll need:

- A function in your migration to open your file and interact with the copy methods
- A `RunPython` operation in your migration's `operations` list to invoke the function

Example, using Django 1.8.4, Python 2.7.10, psycopg2 2.6.1 -

```
from django.db import models, migrations

def forwards(apps, schema_editor):
    with open('./path/to/file.csv', 'r') as infile:
        with schema_editor.connection.cursor() as stmt:
            #for finer control, use copy_expert instead
            stmt.copy_from(infile, 'your_table', sep=',')

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        #this runs your function
        migrations.RunPython(forwards)
    ]
```

Some notes:

- The `file` object passed to `copy` is essentially `STDIN` in the statement.
- The copy command can be picky about columns; using `copy_expert` you can control all the same options as the command: format, headers, delimiter, etc.

For more info on the `copy_*` methods, check the psycopg2 docs: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html

Comment: Thank you. The method `copy_from()` solves the `copy` for one statement. Unfortunately there are several copy statements in my dump file. But I can cut it into N pieces.

Comment: Ah, I didn't make that connection. I suppose you do have a few different options - 1) cut the file (careful to parse out the SQL statement), 2) revisit how the data is generated, or 3) spawn the psql command via `process.popen`. #3 is a bit more fragile depending on where the command is going to get run. For #2, you could go straight to .csv using the `copy_to` method for the data you are interested in, and omit the SQL statement in each dump.